# What's the prefix for binary in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, binary

It's neither `0x` nor `0`; what is it? Is there?

Comment: Start the number with `0b` for example `0b1010101` (you need at least PHP 5.4)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As of PHP 5.4+ the prefix for binary number is:

```
0b
```

---

For ealier version, there is no such prefix. Instead, you can use `0x`, for hexadecimal.

For more informations, see the **[Integers section of the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)**.

Still, if you really need to write values using binary before PHP 5.4, you can use the [`bindec`](https://www.php.net/bindec) function, that takes a string containing the binary, and returns the corresponding value.

For example, the following portion of code :

```
echo bindec('10011');
```

Will get you :

```
19
```

But note you shouldn't do that too often : calling a function to do that each time the script is executed is quite bad for performances ^^

Instead, it's really a better solution to write your values using hexadecimal, where each digit codes for 4 bits.

Answer (score 49):

[New in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) is the binary prefix, `0b`.  Think about portability when using it though; you'll need to be able to guarantee the server runs PHP 5.4+.

Comment: The accepted answer could be the correct at the moment the question happend, but currently this is the correct answer, just a link to support Brads answer:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 2):

From PHP 5.4+ there is, in fact, a prefix: `0b`.

Current info in [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> Binary integer literals are available since PHP 5.4.0.
>
> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.

---

**Mar 24 '10 at 11:31 (original answer):**

I don't think there is one. Prefix `0` if for octal and `0x` is for hexadecimal.

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> Integer can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), or octal (base 8) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +).
>
> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x.

Answer (score 1):

Check [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php): PHP only supports decimal, hexadecimal and octal integer notation, but you can use [bindec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) instead.

Also, keep in mind that each hex digit represents 4 bits, so it's easy to convert between binary notation and hex. The same is true for octal, but for various reasons it's used less often in practice.