# Storing class constants (for use as bitmask) in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, constants

Let's say I have a class called `Medium` which can represent different types of media. For instance:

- uploaded video
- embedded video
- uploaded image
- embedded image

I represent these types with contants, like this:

```
class MediumAbstract
{
    const UPLOAD       = 0x0001;
    const EMBED        = 0x0010;
    const VIDEO        = 0x0100;
    const IMAGE        = 0x1000;

    const VIDEO_UPLOAD = 0x0101; // for convenience
    const VIDEO_EMBED  = 0x0110; // for convenience
    const IMAGE_UPLOAD = 0x1001; // for convenience
    const IMAGE_EMBED  = 0x1010; // for convenience

    const ALL          = 0x1111; // for convenience
}
```

Thus, it is easy for me to do a combined search on them on an (abstract) repository, with something like:

```
{
    public function findAllByType( $type )
    {
        ...
    }
}

$media = $repo->findAllByType( MediumAbstract::VIDEO | MediumAbstract::IMAGE_UPLOAD );
// or
$media = $repo->findAllByType( MediumAbstract::ALL );
// etc..
```

How do you feel about using these constant values in a concrete repository like a database? Is it ok? Or should I substitute them with meaningful data in the database.

```
Table medium:

| id |                type | location    | etc..
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 | use constants here? | /some/path  | etc..
```

(Of course I'll only be using the meaningful constants: VIDEO_UPLOAD, VIDEO_EMBED, IMAGE_UPLOAD and IMAGE_EMBED)

Comment: Not really a community wiki question IMO.

Comment: +1 Pekka. Community wiki makes me not answer. I like getting reputation points for bothering to answer questions.

Comment: I'm sort of asking a subjective (How do you feel about...) question. But I'll unwiki it... and see how the community feels about it. :)

Comment: ... which doesn't seem possible. :( Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

In mySQL, I would use `SET`. They are stored internally using the smallest amount of data, but give you a predefined clear text representation of the value:

```
SET('UPLOAD','EMBED','VIDEO','IMAGE'); // costs 1 byte
```

[Documentation on SET](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html)

You can apply database queries: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IN ("UPLOAD", "EMBED")`

If you use that, it would probably be easier to make the constants match the string values:

```
class MediumAbstract
{
    const UPLOAD       = "UPLOAD";
    const EMBED        = "EMBED";
    const VIDEO        = "VIDEO";
    const IMAGE        = "IMAGE";
```

(What you're doing right now: `0x0001` is not a bit mask anyway, but a hexadecimal value, isn't it? More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507208/whats-the-prefix-for-binary-in-php))

Comment: Hi Pekka, thanks for your answer. Good that you mention mysql, as this is my DB of choice. So I added the tag. I believe the hex representation is still considered a bitmask as it still allows bitwise operations on them (not completely sure though). The hex values just illustrate the values more clear. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243712/why-use-hex also about this. Your solution is sound, but doesn't allow the bitwise operations on them. And I like using bitwise operations. That's why I asked the question.