# Binary notation for bit comparison

Tags: php, javascript, syntax, binary

Can you help me to write a number in its binary notation in PHP code **and** Javascript.

158 is decimal, 0xFF is hexa, 0154 is octa but how is binary ?

I want to set a value in php and read it in Javascript :

PHP:

```
$error &= 1000 (here must be the binary notation)
$error &= 0010
```

Javascript :

```
if (error & 0010) {alert(1)}
```

Thank you very much, your help is appreciated.

Part of the answer is here, there seems to be nothing for PHP :
[What's the prefix for binary in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507208/whats-the-prefix-for-binary-in-php)

Comment: This isn't possible in JavaScript. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803145/is-there-0b-or-something-similar-to-represent-a-binary-number-in-javascript

Comment: You could just write it in hex.  It's not as straightforward as binary, but 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, ... 0x40, 0x80 enable you to declare specific bits as on.

Comment: @Nicolas Thery - for all intents and purposes, "binary" == hex.  Deal with it :)  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary literals don't exist in php.  Binary manipulations are usually done in hex,

```
error & 0010 (binary)
```

can be replaced with

```
error & 0x2
```

Also, see this related post [What's the prefix for binary in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507208/whats-the-prefix-for-binary-in-php)

Comment: Decimal works, but in general you should look into hex for thinking about and coding binary numbers.  It is trivial to look at a hex number of any size and convert to binary (and vice versa).  Decimal is much harder to convert to binary in your head, except for very small numbers.

Answer (score 5):

The PHP notation is:

```
0b0010
```

...but only in [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) and up.

Answer (score -1):

In a end, there is no notation, I will use the decimal value of my binaries and put the binary value in comment :

PHP:

```
$error &= 8; //1000 
$error &= 2; //0010
```

Javascript :

```
if (error & 2) {alert(1)}
```

Comment: Don't use decimal. Become comfortable with hex.

Comment: @Nicolas, hexadecimal has the advantage of being "aligned" in the same way as binary is. Each character is effectively a 4-bit group. It's quite useful visually when you need to consider some flags in your head, especially on longer numbers. E.g. this calculation becomes obvious `0x1000 & 0x1234 = 0x1000`: you can do the bitwise operation on the character at this position. In decimal, what's `4096 & 4660`?