# User permissions binary/decimal confusion after unexpected behavior

Tags: php

First of all I do not understand why some people are using binary number and powers of two for permissions. Is it because they stand for true/false with 1/0 from backwards relation?

Ex: `1010 means false, true, false, true` ?

My question is following. `15` in decimal is same as `1111` in binary, BUT:

```
DEFINE ('READ',1);
DEFINE ('WRITE',2);
DEFINE ('EDIT',4);
DEFINE ('DELETE',8);

$current = 15;

if ($current & READ) print("can read <br />");
if ($current & WRITE) print("can write <br />");
if ($current & EDIT) print("can edit <br />");
if ($current & DELETE) print("can delete <br />");
```

This outputs that all permissions are allowed, as I expect. However, if I change 15 with `1111` then it shows only 3 of them that are allowed not all four (`delete` permission comes as invalid):

```
DEFINE ('READ',1);
DEFINE ('WRITE',2);
DEFINE ('EDIT',4);
DEFINE ('DELETE',8);

$current = 1111;

if ($current & READ) print("can read <br />");
if ($current & WRITE) print("can write <br />");
if ($current & EDIT) print("can edit <br />");
if ($current & DELETE) print("can delete <br />");
```

Is not it strange? Do I understand it incorrectly? I need some help to understand this. Should I store permissions as decimals or binaries in db?

Comment: `1111` is one thousand one hundred and eleven, not binary 1111

Comment: Also see this [StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507208/whats-the-prefix-for-binary-in-php)

Comment: Use `bindec` to convert binary to decimal.

Comment: How does the interpreter know that 1111 is not decimal but binary? It is not psychic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mensi and @datasage says in the comments, 1111 is not the number 1111 in binary, is the number 1111 in decimal!. If you want to put your permissions in binary (to better readability, for example) you can use [bindec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php):

```
$current = bindec('1111'); //Is the same as $current = 15;
```

Comment: am I right that if you read binary reverse it matches order of true/false of your definitions with values of power of 2?

Comment: Yes, that's the way binary works. 2 = 10, 4 = 100, 8 = 1000 ...

Comment: This technique is know as bitwise: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_wise