# In programming languages, what is typically the way used to represent binary values?

Tags: binary

I'm not asking about a particular language, but just in general. I know that, for example, #0x or simply 0x is put before the number, or an h is placed after the number, to refer to hexadecimal.

Is there a similar "standard" for binary?

Comment: Wrong place to ask (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate), but several languages are using `0b` prefix, and some others (notably standard C or C++ without e.g. GNU extensions) don't accept binary notation at all.

Comment: Similar [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507208/whats-the-prefix-for-binary-in-php)

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer, but if this is the wrong place, would you mind directing me to where such questions should go (for the future)?

Comment: It's not clear that this question belongs anywhere, except maybe as a Wikipedia entry. Why would you need to know `just in general`? If you're programming in language X, you need to know how to do it in that language, and a general answer does you no good.

Comment: Hexadecimal or octal numbers are easy to convert into binary. Which is why (I think) binary numbers aren't that popular.

Comment: @KevinMills Possibly http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also hexadecimal notation you mention is not standard among all languages. Delphi/Pascal had $00000000 for hexadecimal, for example.

Comment: "A general answer does you no good." I'm writing a compiler for a language that is basically Thumb, but with a more HLL-esque syntax, so I wanted implicit support for hex, decimal, and binary (because people'd be working with registers).

Comment: So, if some kind of standard existed, it would be useful to know because it'd help people use it, unlike if I chose something random (such as #0xy to preface binary numbers).

Comment: I happen to like the convention used by 6502 assemblers: prefix numbers with a unary $ for hex, % for binary, and & for octal.  An alternative would be to use C-ish prefix of 0x for hex, 0b for binary, and 0q for octal (I really dislike the use of `0` by itself as an octal prefix!)  I've seen a few notations that use more than two extra characters to the number string, but that seems wasteful.  I don't think you necessarily need to pick just one representation, though; it's common for assemblers to support 0x1234 for hex as well as some other format; one could do likewise with 0b10111.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the popular languages don't have a way to enter binary literals. Common Lisp does it using `#b` prefix, and IIRC PL/I uses a `b` suffix. Those are the only ones I can think of off the top of my head that allow it.

I found a page at [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Literals/Integer) that describes how to enter integer literals in many different languages, including specifying radix.

Comment: Ocaml accepts `0b111` for the number seven in binary notation

Answer (score 0):

`b` is used to represent binary numbers. Very few languages provides this support.

One best example is `verilog` / `system verilog` e.g. `4'b0101`