# Bitwise XOR two variables

Tags: php, bitwise-xor

I have two variables: `$a` and `$b`, I want to get the XOR of them.

```
$a = bindec('00110111001010000011101000111010');
$b = bindec('00111110001101100011100100101011');          
          //(11110110111000011111110011101110) <---This is what I want  
$c = $a ^ $b;
echo $c = decbin($c);
```

Why does it give me '1001000111100000001100010001' and not '11110110111000011111110011101110'?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 1):

`xor` is the boolean XOR. Use `^` for the [bitwise XOR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

```
php> true xor false;
bool(true)
php> true xor true;
bool(false)
php> 5^8;
int(13)
php> 5 xor 8;
bool(false)
```

You can use binary literals as of PHP 5.4 and [`bindec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) for older PHP versions. The numbers in your example are treated as decimal (or octal if they start with a zero).

```
php> 0b101010;
int(42)
php> bindec('101010');
int(42)
```

Comment: if I write "01010^ 11011" i get "10507".

Comment: @Michael You are using decimal / octal numbers. Use `0b01010` (works as of PHP 5.4) or `bindec` to convert it to decimal.

Comment: 10507 decbin = 10100100001011. issent 01010 ^ 11011 = 10011?

Comment: @Michael I said `bindec`, not `decbin`, see my edit of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$c=$a ^ $b
```

Here's the doc http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

If you want to use binary numbers like you posted, put '0b' in front of them. Otherwise they are interpreted as decimals. This only works for PHP 5.4 and above ([What's the prefix for binary in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507208/whats-the-prefix-for-binary-in-php))

```
$a = 0b01010
$b = 0b11011
```